# Not understanding the point with delegates/events and publisher/subscribers

Tags: c#

I'm reading and reading, but I still can't get the point and how to use delegates/events and publisher/subscribers? I know that a delegate is a class that contains references to one or more methods and that it's used to send methods to another methods.

The thing I don't get is how I should determine the role of publischer/suubscriber. Let's take an example. A taxicentral and it's cabs. Is the taxicentral the publischer and the cabs the subscribers, whating to get driving orders from the taxicentral? But the cabs could also be publisher and report back there position and the address they are heading for to the taxicentral that, then is a subscriber of the cabs!?

I need inspiration and I'm looking for som beginners code to get a view of how this is working. Is there someone who have some minutes left to reply to this answer with some simple code? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to think of events, publishers/subscribers, etc...is to think of the cloud and the way it tends to function.  In a cloud based system, any entity can register to listen for any type of event, OR can publish any event that it wants.  Anyone listening, will get that data.

In your example: Taxi central could publish/push events like Shift Change, Traffic Accident as (Location), Taxi Requested at (Location), or other similar things that the entire group of cabs would be listening for.  The individual cabs would be publishing things like Pickup At (Location), Drop Off at (Location), Accident at (Location); that Central would be logging for its own purposes. Other cabs could if they wanted to ALSO be listening for these same events, so that they would know where and how close other cabs are to their own location, or if there is an accident that another cab reported, or similar.

Cloud events however are a specific implementation of the event system.  Its much more common to specifically subscribe to events.  A cab object, when created, would immediately subscribe itself to the Central events, and the central system when dispatching the cab would make certain that it subscribed itself to that cab's events.

In this way, both objects serve the role of both publisher and subscriber.  Its only really specific to a single event.  In my example `PickupAt(Location)` would be published by a Cab, and Subscribed to by Central.  Thus, for that event, Cab is the publisher, and Central is the Subscriber.  In general, Who serves what role depends entirely on the system design and what events are being created.  Its not something that can really be generalized, because the entire setup could be changed, or even reversed, if you setup the events differently.  That I think is the most important part.

**Delegates as a whole**

In its simplest term, a Delegate is a Reference.  It can reference a class, more commonly it can reference a method in a class, or the call to a method in a class.  It can even contain an entire method call inside itself.  Its really a very versatile object, in that it can do many things.  In the context of events, the delegate actually references the call to the function that implements the event.

**Simple Event Code**

```
public class c1
{
    public event Eventhandler DoStuff;

    public c1()
    {

    }

    public void OnDoStuff()
    {//this actually makes the event happen
        if (DoStuff != null)
            DoStuff(this, null);
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    c1 x = new c1();
    x.DoStuff += new EventHandler(ThingFunction);

    x.OnDoStuff();//this is how you would fire the event deliberately
}

public void ThingFunction(object sender, EventArgs x)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Something Happened");
}
```

c1 contains the event `DoStuff`, Main subscribes to this event. When the code calls `x.OnDoStuff()` from ANYWHERE, which is very handy if say you pass x, or a reference to it, into other classes where actual code is processed, then the handler way back in main, no matter how many layers deep the `x.OnDoStuff()` call originates from, will execute.

Rather more specifically, once X is created, it can be passed somewhere else.  As long as some function is assigned to `x.DoStuff`, whenever and wherever you call the method `x.OnDoStuff()` from, the function that is assigned to `x.DoStuff` will execute.  That is how event subscriptions work.  `x.OnDoStuff()` is the code call that publishes the event `x.DoStuff`, and any class...in fact any number of classes, you can have multiple subscribers after all, will be able to catch the published event.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I guess it will be more complicated if I have to use WPF windows also. The taxi central is the main window and the all the cabs have subscriber windows for illustration purpose. Well I have to do it in small steps

Comment: In my instructions I shall define three EventArgs info classes that is derived from the EventArgs?! I'm not sure what that means? The derived from EventArgs part?

Comment: is this Homework?  Please add the homework tag if that's the case.  You seem to have a rather specific set of requirements...

EventArgs is a generic class that EventHander uses to pass arguments into subscriber functions.  By Creating custom implementations of that class, you allow your events to publish more specific data than simply `DoStuff`.  You would populate this data in the `OnDoStuff` publishing call.

Comment: In my example...`PickUpAt(Location)`...Location would have to be defined in a custom class, that way when publishing the event using an `OnPickUp(Location)` method call, you would be able to add location to the event args that the subscriber function recieves.

Answer (score 0):

You have to think in "Event Driven" terms. In your example there could be publisher roles for both the taxicentral and the cabs as well as subscriber roles for the taxicentral and cab.

For example, if the taxicentral has an update to push to all the cabs it can have an event that it raises and the cabs listen to. Cabs then could have an event they raise when they pick up and drop off someone, and the taxicentral would listen to all those events.

Does this help?

Comment: Hmm, perhaps, so every possible event should then be a own class or a method?

Comment: delegates are custom events that you create. Events that have in them, packaged, the data you want. This might not be anything beyond, "hey, the event happened", but it might be, "the event happened, and it was taxi #34". Then each instance of an event you want to trigger and catch is created using the delegates.

Answer (score 0):

Delegates are not used to send methods to other methods. They are used to call methods, which may be unknown at compile time.

Let's look at a simpe example. Consider, you write a calculator, where the user can choose the arguments and the operation. The operation can be a delegate to a method that executes the calculation. Therefore, you don't have to worry about how to store the operations. Furthermore, the calculator does not need to know every operation, because the user will provide it.

A common example of delegates are callback functions. If you start a long term procedure in a second thread, you may want to be notified, if the thread has finished. You could do this by providing a delegate to the thread that is invoked, when the procedure has finished.

Events are kind of a special type of delegates. They are used, when an object wants to notify others of a status change or similar actions. The special thing about that is that the object itself does not need to know, which objects are interested in the changes. Instead, those objects subscribe to the event. The object that provides the event only has to invoke the event's delegate and all subscriber delegates are invoked.

As Justin C already explained, both the taxi central and the cab can act as subscribers and publishers. It depends on who is interested in what. And if everyone is allowed to subscribe to the events. If only the taxi central is allowed to get the information, a callback method would be more suitable.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Not sure how I should code this? I can't find any simple example of codes. Could you just show some code to give me some inspiration?